# Flink metric when job fails is not what i expected in Prometheus

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

I'm currently trying to monitor Flink streaming jobs with Prometheus.
One of the requirements is to send an alert when a job has failed. 
According to documentation the metric flink_jobmanager_job_downtime emits -1 for completed jobs, so I have created an alert using the following expression.

```
expr: flink_jobmanager_job_downtime{job_id=".*"} == -1
```

The problem is that I checked Prometheus web UI and the metric flink_jobmanager_job_downtime for a failed job never emits -1 for a failed job.
In fact it only emits 0 so the alert never triggers.
Am I missing something or is this really the expected behavior?

Comment: How do you know the job has actually failed?

Comment: Hi David, I know it failed because i checked it at the Flink Web UI, which shows the job has reached a FAILED status.